# Nemo (or another fiile manager): add subfolders to bookmarks

Tags: filemanager, nemo

Nemo has left panel with 'Computer', 'Bookmarks', 'Devices' and 'Network' sections.

I know how I can add a folder to 'Bookmarks'.

But I want to add them in hierarchical structure, say:

- Bookmarks (standard section)

  - Downloads (standard bookmark)
  - ... (other standard bookmarks)
  - Projects (my bookmark folder, not a real dir)

    - Project 1 (subfolder in Projects bookmark, real dir)
    - Project 2 (real dir)
    - ...

Is this possible? Or, at least, can I add my own section on the top level with my bookmarks?

If not, is there any file manager that allows it?

Answer (score 1):

Nemo works similar to Nautilus.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will add a bookmark. ([source](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-manage-bookmarks-in-nautilus/))

Comment: Yes, but question is how to arrange them hierarhically.